# How can I duplicate a collection of models childed to an empty, and still toggle the visibility of individual models?

Tags: linked-data, collections, instances, visibility

There's a bit more to my question than I could explain in the title.

For each instance of the empty, I need the models to appear in the same position relative to the empty. Also, if I move or rotate a model relative to its parent empty, or child a new model to the empty, that same change needs to happen to all instances of that model.

Finally, I also need to be able to toggle visibility of individual models from each instance of the collection - this is the biggest stumbling block I've found.

I've been trying to work this out for three days now, but nothing I try gets the results I need. Putting the models in a collection, then instancing the collection just gives a blob of models where every part is visible, and in the wrong location relative to its empty. Including the original empty in the collection show none of the models at all.

I'll be grateful for any help or advice, even if its just confirmation that what I want isn't possible.